# Node.Js passing data from Postman and getting it set with Controller code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman

I am having a table named "Account" and it has a field named "seller" which points to "User" table `seller:{model:"User"}`. Now I have to make a controller function such that from postman if I pass account id and user id `{account:"", user:""}`then through controller code the user id which was passed in postman should get set in "seller" field of "Account" table. Please help I am not getting any idea of how to make this controller function!!!!

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am not getting any idea of how to make the function which could set data coming from postman to the table field